# Change title of a content type

Tags: theming, entities, nodes, 7

I have a custom content type named 'product'. Every content of type product has a serial number of the product as the title.
But while displaying the title I want to override it from two of the CCK fields of the product.
Please take a look at this [page](http://www.aarfid.info/product/ABS-Key-Fob/2050-1011-70-0490-01).

I want to concatenate Manufacturer and Chip and display it as the title. I am a beginner in Drupal.

Comment: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in garland_preprocess_node() (line 123 of C:\wamp\www\in2Tags\themes\garland\template.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For altering the saved title, try [auto_nodetitle](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module, it can do what you want there.

1. Download and install the module
2. Enable the module in Drupal
3. Edit the relevant content type settings ( `Admin > Structure > Content types` )
4. Set the `Automatic title generation` option, using [field tokens](http://drupal.org/node/1299662) for the field values

If you want to update the *display* only, then you can use a node.tpl.php template preprocess function

e.g in your theme `template.php` file, replace THEMENAME with your theme name.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  $node &= $vars['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'product') {
    $text = $node->field_manufacturer[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] . ' ' . $node->field_chip[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $vars['title'] = check_plain($text);
  }
}
```

[Clear theme registry cache](http://drupal.org/node/337176) after adding a new preprocess function

Comment: I want to keep the title as serial number(because it is unique) but only while displaying I want to override it.

Comment: @vaibhav Answer updated with manual override option

Comment: I understand it now, but I guess this code snippet will override title of all content types. I want only products title to be overridden. Thanks.

Comment: OK, answer updated. That should do it :)

Comment: Thanks, it is quite interesting in template.php. Is there a way to know what properties $var has. Maybe a variable dump can work here.

Comment: can probably do: `drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($vars,1).'</pre>'); `or else dpm($vars) with devel module.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7081/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-david-thomas)